# 2d Arrays Integer Sequence

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, 2d

I am trying to count the number of times an integer appears in a 2D Array and print the count. I am new in Java and still learning.

**This is the 2D array I am using:**

```
System.out.println("Array\t Nummbers");
    int Array[][] = { { 39, 16, 13, 1, 35, 31, 47 }, { 39, 2, 45, 44, 38, 19, 40 }, { 39, 43, 33, 16, 20, 9, 30 },
            { 42, 23, 26, 27, 1, 48, 47 }, { 18, 25, 47, 31, 46, 36, 20 }, { 21, 34, 19, 6, 4, 25, 29 },
            { 30, 5, 22, 23, 11, 47, 19 }, { 34, 30, 7, 31, 16, 45, 41 }, { 37, 9, 7, 42, 45, 24, 5 },
            { 39, 34, 28, 5, 37, 17, 22 }, { 42, 47, 34, 15, 35, 41, 28 }, { 22, 8, 46, 30, 36, 28, 11 };
```

**I am using the following code  that I found in here, I made some changes, but I am still not able to fix it.**

```
System.out.println("\t" + countCharInRow(Array));
public static Map<Character, Integer> countCharInRow(char[][] myArray) {
 Map<Character, Integer> charOccurences = new HashMap<>();
 Set<Character> rowCharacters = new HashSet<>();
 for(char[] row : myArray) {
    for(char charInArray = row) { // put all the chars on the line in the set
        rowCharacters.add(row);
    }
    for(char charInSet : rowCharacters) {
        Integer occurences = charOccurences.get(charInSet);
        if(occurences == null) { // first occurence
            charOccurences.put(charInSet, 1);
        } else {  // increment
            charOccurences.put(charInSet, occurences.intValue() + 1);
        }
    }
 }
 return charOccurences;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The question is not written in English. Please explain yourself better. Do you mean you want the function to produce a map of the frequencies of all integers in the 2d array?

Comment: Thank you... trying to find out and print how many times all and any of each numbers appears in that big array .....Hope you understood,sorry for my bad english!

Comment: So if `'a'` appears 3 times in the first row and 2 times in the second, you want `'a': 5` to be added to the map?

Comment: Yes sir excactly this..

Comment: So no need to first put the characters inside a set. In fact, that will make you count each character in a row at most once because a set has no duplicates. Added an answer in this spirit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countCharInMatrix(char[][] mat) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charOccurences = new HashMap<>();
    for(char[] row : mat) {
        for(char charInRow : row) {
            Integer occurences = charOccurences.get(charInRow);
            if(occurences == null) { // first occurence
                charOccurences.put(charInRow, 1);
            } else {  // increment
                charOccurences.put(charInRow, occurences.intValue() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return charOccurences;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer... same error like last one in system.out.print

The method countCharInMatrix(char[][]) in the type methodFinal is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])

And when changing to Int the bigger problems starts....

Comment: If you send a matrix of ints, then you need to change the type of the matrix argument to `int[] [] `, `Character` into `Integer` in both local variable and return type, and `char` to `int` in both for loops

Comment: Thank you for fixing my Matrix m8.... i really appreciate it!!!If my idea works i will send it to you also for some cash more ;) Have Fun

Comment: You deserve to know what my matrix was created of

    {1=7, 2=4, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=4, 7=4, 8=6, 9=4, 10=1, 11=3, 12=5, 13=4, 15=2, 16=8, 17=8, 18=4, 19=4, 20=3, 21=7, 22=7, 23=7, 24=2, 25=3, 26=2, 27=4, 28=6, 29=4, 30=6, 31=4, 32=3, 33=4, 34=6, 35=2, 36=4, 37=4, 38=5, 39=5, 40=3, 41=5, 42=6, 43=3, 44=3, 45=5, 46=4, 47=8, 48=2, 49=3}